# How to embed video at certain height in a landing page, also start after few seconds - like airbnb?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video

I need to create a landing page which is covered 50% by a nice video. And the video need only to be started after 1 or 2 seconds (just like a airbnb website)

Below is the code I have at the moment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Demo video homepage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<style type="text/css">
#videodiv{
z-index: -1;
height: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header id="container">
<div id="videodiv" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video id="myvideo" loop="loopd" preload="auto" class="embed-responsive-item" autoplay="autoplay">
      <source type="video/webm" src="../media/bbb.webm"></source>
      <source type="video/mp4" src="../media/bbb.mp4"></source>
    </video>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" as suggested by Bootstrap. Viewing in Chrome, it does always come full screen. In Safari, it seems to recognise the percentage and is maintaining instructed height.

- How can I fix these issues?
- Another question I have is that if connectivity is slow, I can imagine video taking time to download. I wonder what solution is widely used to place-hold until the video is downloaded?

Comment: In the video html markup if you have `autoplay`, you don´t need `preload`...check this out ...http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start the video a few seconds after page load you can work with setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('video').play(); }, 2000);
```

Where 2000 stands for the milliseconds = 2 seconds.

Have you tried to define #videodiv as a block using display:block.
Otherwise you can force the height by "height:50% !important;". An alternative to the percentage is areference to the actual viewport height: "height: 50vh;".

Comment: Playing after few seconds worked well. hence I accept the answer. Although the height is still an issue for me.